# Add composite product to order programmatically in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am struggling to add a composite product to to WC orders programatically. I have been going through the source code to try and figure this out, but keep running into errors.

What I am doing right now is creating at instance of `WC_CP_Order` to get access to the method `add_composite_to_order($composite, $order, $quantity, $args)`

```
        $wc_cp = new WC_CP_Order(); // Create instance of WC_CP_Order

        $composite_product =  wc_get_product('39082'); // Get the composite product
        $order = wc_get_order(39250); // Order that I want to add the composite product to
        $args = array(
            'configuration' => array(
                1620281459 => array(                    // ID of the component.
                    'quantity'          => 1,           // Qty of composited product, will fall back to min.
                    'discount'          => 0,           // Composited product discount, defaults to the defined value.
                    'attributes'        => array(),     // Array of selected variation attribute names, sanitized.
                    'variation_id'      => 39114,       // ID of chosen variation, if applicable.
                    'args'              => array()      // Custom composited item args to pass into 'WC_Order::add_product()'.
                )
            )
        )

        $wc_cp->add_composite_to_order($composite_product, $order, 1, $args);
```

This configuration returns a 500 error when I trigger this function (this is just all of the code inside the function).

I am probably just overlooking something very simple, but so far am unable to find it. There are the docs that I have been using: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/composite-products/. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!